# Why can't Windows Server 2008 create cookies?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, authentication, cookies, http-cookie

Scenario:

I have a web application (SnapshotServer) which uses a WebBrowser control to take a snapshot images of a web page.

I use a WebBrowser control within SnapshotServer to navigate to a entry page of a secure web application (ImageHost) and then redirects me to my required page.
The ImageHost application is protected by FormsAuthentication, which uses cookies. The entry page I navigate to takes care of logging me in - which will create an Auth cookie.

Once a response is generated from the ImageHost, I convert the result within the WebBrowser control to an image.

Issue:

When I run SnapshotServer on my PC (Windows 7, IE8), using IIS7, and navigate to ImageHost on my development server (Windows 2008 R2, IE8), the result is as required -
I'm logged into ImageHost and redirected to the page I want an image of.
When I run SnapshotServer on any Windows 2008 R2 server, using IIS7, and navigate to ImageHost on my development server (Windows 2008 R2, IE8), the result is not as required -
ImageHost fails to log in - so my image is of the login page. The reason it fails to log in is that it isn't creating an Auth cookie.

So I'd like to know if anyone can tell me why the WebBrowser control, when run from a Windows 2008 server, cannot create cookies.

Comment: please edit your question and tags, on the tags you put sql-server not windows server this question is not related to sql. Another thing is that there is no Windows Server 2008 R3, only R2. Did you copy and paste you development server is functioning and not functioning at the same time?

Comment: Hi @Euclid try clarifying what you are doing, its weird, you are running the app on your machine and accessing from other and its working, when you run it on another machine (the server) and access it through other machine it doesn't works? Another thing what WebBrowser control is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408611/)